# Telethon await doesn't work properly

Tags: python, async-await, telethon

I want to download a couple of music by a music bot. This is my implementation. For a specific query,  sometimes works fine but sometimes not. It seems that `await` doesn't work because it couldn't retrieve messages by `get_messages` function. Do you know what's wrong here?

```
async def get_music_url(client, query):
    await client.send_message('melobot', query)

    messages = await client.get_messages('melobot')
    btn_txt_music = find_button(messages[0], "\N{MUSICAL NOTE}")
    print("Music: ", btn_txt_music)
    await client.send_message('melobot', btn_txt_music)

    messages_2 = await client.get_messages('melobot')
    btn_txt_128kb = find_button(messages_2[0], "128")
    await client.send_message('melobot', btn_txt_128kb)

    messages_3 = await client.get_messages('melobot', limit=2)
    print('music_url: ', find_url(messages_3[0].message))

    await client.disconnect()


def test_music(query):
    client = authorize_telegram_client()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_music_url(client, query))
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: what is the actual error or exception?

Comment: When I send a song name as my query, this bot returns a list of songs. I passed the retrieved result to a function named 'find_button' to find the correct button between them. I try this code for a single query multiple times. Sometimes, I get the following error from `find_button` function:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rows'
It seems that the input message of this function is empty and telethon doesn't retrieve anything.